# Vending async JavaScript libraries: modules versus stubbing

Tags: javascript

When creating a new browser-based JavaScript library, developers would normally choose one of the following techniques to get around the issue of asynchronous script loading and the general nondeterministic way JS libraries are loaded:

- Vend the library through a module-dependancy system (e.g. RequireJS, AMD, CommonJS etc.)
- Create a library "stub", which can be inserted inline and which records the method calls on said stub, and then replay them when the library loads fully from an async script.

To take a concrete example, say we have a library `A` with a method `x` which we want to vend to external users.

If we're using modules, the end-user would write:

```
waitForLibrary("A").then((A) => A.x());
```

And through stubs:

```
/* Stub module inline/globally */
let A = mockModule({x: recordMethodCalls();});
...
/* Users call x() method normally */
A.x();
...
/* When the full library loads, existing method calls are replayed */
A.x.replay(() => /* Actually do stuff */
```

However, each method has it's disadvantages, in that:

- **You cannot call a module before it is loaded.** For example, if `A` is a library for logging Java Script errors, you would be able to log said errors only after the `A` module loads.
- **Stubbing a complex APIs will result in a lot of inline code.** If your library/module has method which returns objects, with methods which return object etc., then all these execution paths will have to be stubbed, leading to complex stubbing logic and a lot of JS inserted inline/globally. The main reason for using async JS libraries is to reduce page load times, and a lot of stubbing code will nullify this benefit.

Are there any alternatives besides the two techniques to vend JavaScript APIs?

(To note that a requirement is to use vanilla.js with backwards compatibility for ES5, so no async functions).